# Enabling zoom in <dxc:XYDiagram2D>

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, devexpress

The XYDiagram2D in the xaml file is from DevExpress.Xpf.Charts which doesn't have the "EnableAxisXZooming" member. That member, however, is there in DevExpress.Xtracharts. I want to enable zooming in my chart. Please suggest how do i solve this problem.

XAML file -

```
<Window x:Class="Bubble2DChart.Window1" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:dxc="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/charts" Title="Window1" Height="350" Width="620"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Bubble2DChart">
<Grid>
    <dxc:ChartControl Name="TestChart"  >
        <dxc:ChartControl.CrosshairOptions  >
            <dxc:CrosshairOptions ShowValueLine="True" ShowValueLabels="True"/>
        </dxc:ChartControl.CrosshairOptions>
        <dxc:ChartControl.Diagram>
            <dxc:XYDiagram2D Name="xy_name" >

            </dxc:XYDiagram2D>
        </dxc:ChartControl.Diagram>
    </dxc:ChartControl>
</Grid>
```

cs file -

```
using System.Windows;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
//using DevExpress.Xpf.Charts;
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;
using DevExpress.XtraCharts;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace Bubble2DChart
{

    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += Window1_Loaded;
        }

        private void Window1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var csvTable = new DataTable();
            var series = new DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.BubbleSeries2D();
            var series2 = new DevExpress.Xpf.Charts.BubbleSeries2D();
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            /*
            get data and add to series
            */

            // add to diagram
            TestChart.Diagram.Series.Add(series);
            TestChart.Diagram.Series.Add(series2);


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So turns out EnableAxisXNavigation handles both Navigation AND Zooming so mentioning that field as "true" is enough – Rishi JS just now   Edit   Delete